# Tkinter:change a pixel's color

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I load an image in a TkInter canvas to allow the user to draw a point by a mouse right lick button. After saving the coordinates of the pixel where the mouse button was pressed, I change the pixel in question to red color using OpenCV.

No error occurs, however there is no effect on the picture. I mean, I do not have the expected result.

may be someone could tell me what's wrong ?

```
import PIL.Image
import Image
import ImageTk
from Tkinter import *    
import numpy as np
import cv2    

class ExampleApp(Frame):
   def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master=None)
        self.x = self.y = 0
        self.imcv=None
        self.canvas=None   

   def dessiner(self):
       # Load the imge and allow user to scroll it if it is large.
       self.canvas=Canvas(self,cursor="cross",width=600,height=600)
       self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>",self.on_button_press)
       self.sbarv=Scrollbar(self,orient=VERTICAL)
       self.sbarh=Scrollbar(self,orient=HORIZONTAL)
       self.sbarv.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
       self.sbarh.config(command=self.canvas.xview)

       self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.sbarv.set)
       self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand=self.sbarh.set)

       self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W)
       self.sbarv.grid(row=0,column=1,stick=N+S)
       self.sbarh.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=E+W)
       self.im = PIL.Image.open("image.jpg")
       self.widt,self.heigt=self.im.size
       self.canvas.config(scrollregion=(0,0,self.widt,self.heigt))
       self.tk_im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)
       self.canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor="nw",image=self.tk_im)   


   def on_button_press(self,event):
       self.lecanvas=event.widget
       self.x=self.lecanvas.canvasx(event.x)
       self.y=self.lecanvas.canvasy(event.y)
       self.canvas.create_oval(self.x,self.y, self.x+1,self.y+1,outline='red')
       print self.x,self.y


   def resumer(self):
       self.imcv=cv2.imread("image.jpg")
       self.imcv[self.x,self.y,0]=0
       self.imcv[self.x,self.y,1]=0
       self.imcv[self.x,self.y,2]=255
       cv2.imwrite("result.jpg",self.imcv)
       cv2.namedWindow("gl",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
       cv2.imshow("gl",self.imcv)
       cv2.waitKey(0)
       cv2.destroyAllWindows()






if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=Tk()
    app = ExampleApp(root)
    app.dessiner()
    app.resumer()    
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Note that I also get the cv2 window displayed before the Tkinter window is displayed.

EDIT:

Following the comments of the users below, I guess I can get the coordinates of that pixel I draw on TkInter interface using a red color. So I want to recolor that pixel into red using OpenCV but I guess it does not take effect using OpenCV. Note that I must do this in OpenCV for further image processing:

```
def resumer(self):
       print"inside Resumer function:"
       print"Resume: ({},{})".format(self.x,self.y)
       self.imcv=cv2.imread("image.jpg")
       self.imcv[self.x,self.y,0]=0
       self.imcv[self.x,self.y,1]=0
       self.imcv[self.x,self.y,2]=255
       cv2.imwrite("result.jpg",self.imcv)
       cv2.namedWindow("gl",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
       cv2.imshow("gl",self.imcv)
       cv2.waitKey(0)
       cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The order of calling the is this one now:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=Tk()
    app = ExampleApp(root)
    app.pack()
    app.dessiner()
    root.mainloop()
    app.afficher_pixel()
    app.resumer()
```

Any help is appreciated
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The cv2 window displayed before the Tkinter window because you execute the `resumer()` method before entering `root.mainloop()`. Instead you should either execute `resumer()` in response to an event _or_ after `root.mainloop()` returns (which happens after the Tkinter window is closed).

Comment: @martineau thank you sir, I changed the order of execution you mentioned but then I got a blank TkInter window :(

Comment: Just moving the `app.resumer()` call to after `root.mainloop()` would not have done that. Also, if you want to change the in-memory copy of the image see [this example code](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/PhotoImage#Placing_Pixels_1x1).

Comment: @martineau I had a blank TkInter window because I removed the option `image=self.tk_im`, now that I put it back I get the window displayed with the image, I press the  mouse right button and raw a pixel (point) on the image. However the  color value of that of the pixel is not changed. it does not take effect for some reason.

Comment: @martineau thank you for the link, but I want to do that in OpenCV because in reality I have a larger image processing to run so I prefer to do with openCV but in background without the user's knowledge

Comment: When you say "there is no effect on the picture" which one are you talking about then?

Comment: @martineau I mean: the point I draw on TkInter canvas that holds the picture, I want to render the coordinates of that point (pixel) into red color using OpenCV. So everything is ok except I do not see that pixel rendered to red color when OpenCV window displays that picture

Comment: In that case I would verify that the `self.x` and `self.y` coordinates you got from the Tkinter event are correct.

Comment: @martineau your last remark helped me: in fact, I got the correct `(self.x,self.y)` but inside the `resumer()` function which uses OpenCV, I used `self.x` and `self.y` in an opposite order that is why I did not see the red pixel in OpenCV window in the same place as where I did it in TkInter.

Comment: @martineau your first remark is also too important. Thank you very much. if you want to summerize your comments and write them as an answer I will accept your answer. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention two problems, one about changing the image and another about the cv2 window displayed before the Tkinter window.

The second item is easy, so I'll address it first. It's caused by the fact that you call `root.mainloop()` *after* the call to `app.resumer()` (which displays the cv2 window). You can fix either by executing `app.resumer()` in response to some event — say from clicking a new button you add — or more simply by moving the call to it to *after* root.mainloop() returns (which happens when the Tkinter window is closed by default).

The other problem about changing the pixel to red in the OpenCV window may have something to do with the `self.x` and `self.y` image coordinates you got from the Tkinter `event` being incorrect somehow, so I would check those and make sure you're getting the proper values and using them correctly — for example do you have them in the right order?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the in-memory copy of the image (`self.tk_im`).

Comment: Thank you for help, but same result after removing `image=self.tk_im`. I also get the cv2 window displayed before the Tkinter window is displayed

Comment: @nakkini: I didn't suggest _removing_ it. You need to update the pixels in it. What you see on the screen doesn't reflect changes in the file. You need to either reload the file, or directly set the pixels in the image object.

Comment: In fact, I have the coordinates of that pixel, but I want to use OpenCV to change its color to red. it does not change. I do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `canvas.update()` after you change it. It could be that the code works but just doesn’t show the changes on the screen.